# Create an array with a letter repeated a given number of times given by another array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `a` and i want to create another array `b` with a certain string repeated the number of times specified by `a`

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
s = 'a'
```

i want the `b` to be `np.array(['a','aa','aaa'])`. What would be the numpy way to do it without loops?

Though my use case does not need it but, in general

```
a = np.array([1,2,3])
s = np.array(['a','b','c'])
```

How to get `b` to be `np.array(['a','bb','ccc'])` without loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a built-in method:

```
output = np.core.defchararray.multiply(s,a)
```

Comment: Can save a few chars with `np.char.multiply(s, a)` :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's compare the alternatives:

```
In [495]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) 
     ...: s = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Using the `np.char` function.  Under the covers this applies string multiply to each element of the array (with a loop):

```
In [496]: np.char.multiply(s,a)                                                 
Out[496]: array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype='<U3')
```

An explicit loop.  `i.item()` converts the numpy string to Python string:

```
In [498]: np.array([i.item()*j for i,j in zip(s,a)])                            
Out[498]: array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype='<U3')
```

Another way of creating an array of Python strings:

```
In [499]: s.astype(object)*a                                                    
Out[499]: array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype=object)
```

Timings:

```
In [500]: timeit np.char.multiply(s,a)                                          
21.3 µs ± 975 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [501]: timeit np.array([i.item()*j for i,j in zip(s,a)])                     
13.4 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [502]: timeit s.astype(object)*a                                             
9.16 µs ± 226 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So the explicit loop approach does pretty well.

Another idea - use `frompyfunc`:

```
In [504]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i,j: i*j, 2,1)(s,a)                              
Out[504]: array(['a', 'bb', 'ccc'], dtype=object)
In [505]: timeit np.frompyfunc(lambda i,j: i*j, 2,1)(s,a)                       
6.28 µs ± 56 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I thought of `frompyfunc` because I wondered if we could use broadcasting:

```
In [508]: np.frompyfunc(lambda i,j: i*j, 2,1)(s,a[:,None])                      
Out[508]: 
array([['a', 'b', 'c'],
       ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'],
       ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']], dtype=object)
```

But that kind of broadcasting works for the other methods as well.

`np.vectorize` uses `np.frompyfunc` but does dtype conversions (`frompyfunc` always returns object dtype), but it tends to be slower.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you insist on them being `numpy` objects? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question but you would handle it the same way as a list:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
s = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
new_array = np.array([str(s[i])*a[i] for i in range(len(s))])
print(new_array)
```

Outputs:

> ['a', 'bb', 'ccc']

This assumes `a` and `s` are of equal length, because it was not specified otherwise

Comment: want vectorized way of doing it. I need to apply this to a million rows

Comment: This is a string operation.  There isn't fast compiled numpy code to do it.  Even the `np.char.multiply` just iterates through the array, applying the string multiply.

Comment: @hpaulj atleast it would still do multiprocessing using all my cores which i will have to do explicitly at my end i guess if i use a loop?