# Splitting a numpy chararray and adding characters

Tags: python, regex, string, list, numpy

I have the following data, which is currently a numpy.chararray:

```
>>> radec
chararray(['000000.45+174625.4', '000000.66+145828.8',
       '000000.97+044947.2', ..., '235959.74+100700.4',
       '235959.78+285717.0', '235959.83+344315.0'], dtype='<U18')
```

I'd like to simply split the radec variable after the 9th digit, and then add colons to have two variables as output, e.g.:

```
  00:00:00.45 +17:46:25.4
  00:00:00.66 +14:58:28.8
  ...
  23:59:59.78 +28:57:17.0 
  23:59:59.83 +34:43:15.0
```

Is there are quick and pythonic way of doing this??!!

Comment: Demonstrate the desired action on a single string,

Comment: >>> radec[0] 000000.45+174625.4'  becomes ra[0] = 00:00:00.45 and dec[0] = +17:46:25.4

Comment: @sin, I've just flagged your comment.

Comment: If I have: x = radec.split(), this puts the varibles into a list. But how do I use .split and specifiy to split after 9 characters?

Answer (score 0):

In a recent SO I compared various ways of acting on strings of an array:

[Create an array with a letter repeated a given number of times given by another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55386621/create-an-array-with-a-letter-repeated-a-given-number-of-times-given-by-another/55389551#55389551)

Turned out that `np.char` (or the `chararray` methods) isn't any faster than a list comprehension.  `np.frompyfunc` was fastest.

So based on experience I think you need to focus on modifying just one string, and leave any `numpy` speedup to later.

One complication, as noted, is that when you apply split, you get an array of lists; two words replace the original one.

Without getting into the details I suspect the addition of ':' will require `re`, or some sort of iteration (a list comprehension on the string?).

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to simply split the radec variable after the 9th digit…
>   radec[0] 000000.45+174625.4' becomes ra[0] = 00:00:00.45 and dec[0] = +17:46:25.4

The split can be accomplished by constructing a view of the variable's memory with the appropriate data-type:

```
t = numpy.dtype([('ra', 'U9'), ('dec', 'U9')])
ra  = radec.view(t)['ra']
dec = radec.view(t)['dec']
```

> … and then add colons

This can also be done (ab)using the view method:

```
ra  = [":".join(x) for x in ra .view(numpy.dtype("U2,U2,U5"))]
dec = [":".join(x) for x in dec.view(numpy.dtype("U3,U2,U4"))]
```